# Install Xdebug extension only for PHP7.1

Tags: php, xdebug, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.1

I have PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 installed. When I'm trying to install Xdebug by using `apt-get install php-xdebug`, I'm getting `xdebug.ini` in directories 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1.

I don't need `/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and `/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` extensions, because I'm using only PHP 7.1 version.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care about the other folders ? If it is not causing an error, just ignore it.

Comment: There's no downside to having them in `mods-available`. Just make sure they're not turned on via `mods-enabled` and they'll have no effect.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to figure out, maybe there are some another ways to install Xdebug. I don't want to keep eye on another versions of Xdebug except for PHP 7.1.

Comment: Even if it was enabled, I think that PHP 7.1 will only look for available modules in their own folder.

Comment: Just ignore these folders.

Comment: Okay, what about this command ```find / -name 'xdebug.so' 2> /dev/null```, which gives me three different paths? I need to figure out wich one to choose.

Comment: You already know that you're using the 7.1's PHP version, right? So, choose the path that is related to your PHP version.

Comment: Ok, I have output to command line like this 
```/usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so```
```/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so```
```/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so```.
Which version related to PHP 7.1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142295/discussion-between-viktor-and-lucas-mendes).

Comment: Just make a symlink from `/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` to `/php/7.1/mods-enabled/xdebug.ini` and xdebug will be turned on for PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because php-xdebug is ambiguous and will download the default package which will contain multiple versions for php compatibility, try going to xdebug site and download the code, then make/build it https://xdebug.org/

Comment: I know this option, but tried to find build-in solution. Thanks anyway.)

Comment: @Viktor ah I see - to my knowledge I don't think there is unless you use the latest build of Ubuntu due to it's library sources - if possible try creating a virtual partition with ubuntu 17.04 on it and try seeing if xdebug for php7 is the only one that comes back :)

Comment: I'll try. Cheers.)

Answer (score 5):

try:

`apt install php7.1-xdebug`

If I good understood, you don't want to have many xdebug ini files. Ubuntu supports many php versions, which you can switch if you need. If you want to have single xdebug configuration file, I recommend to create catalog `mods-available` in `/etc/php`, move xdebug.ini there and make symbolic link from all required paths (for apache2, cli for every php version you need) - for example, for PHP 7.1 with Apache

`ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

Comment: This commad  under the hood makes ```apt-get install php-xdebug``` and gave the same result.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: Sure, I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used these commands to get xdebug installed and running on 7.2

```
git clone git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git && cd xdebug 
apt-get install -y php7.2-dev && ./rebuild.sh
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Xdebug has an awesome wizard(form) where you can just paste the content of your php.ini or results of `php -i` command and get step by step instructions on how to go about setting it up.

In my experience, it's the most reliable and error-free method and I have used in vagrant instances with both mod-php and php-fpm 7.1 & 7.2 versions without any issues.

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php